# Inconsistent errors regarding WPF thread ownership

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need help understanding why I am getting "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" errors on one possible solution and not getting it in another solution. Suppose I have a public CollectionViewSource and a public List object with appropriate get/sets.  I needed to start a background thread to download a list of email addresses from a server. (For brevity, I'll skip the download logic) and then bind the result set to a combobox on my view by marshalling control back to the UI. My working solution is as follows:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                       
   // Grab User Email addresses.
   EmailPool = SomeDataSource.Select(u => u.Email).ToList();

   System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         new Action(() =>
         {
             EmailPoolCollectionViewSource.Source = EmailPool;
             EmailPoolCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
                  new SortDescription(String.Empty, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
         }
}
```

Now, since I am relatively new to WPF threading, I started playing with this solution to see how/why I could break it. I noticed that if I remove the Dispatcher code segment (a sure way to break this since I lose access to the UI thread) and change this line:

```
EmailPool = SomeDataSource.Select(u => u.Email).ToList();
```

To this:

```
EmailPoolCollectionViewSource.Source = SomeDataSource.Select(u => u.Email).ToList();
```

The application will throw the "Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" exception on that line. I removed any bindings to either property in the view to try and isolate the issue but I still get the same results. Why is this the case? Both the `EmailPool` and `EmailPoolCollectionViewSource` are declared in my ViewModel and if the background worker thread can access one of them, why can't it access the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it will only break when interacting with a UI control from a different thread.  Interacting with a standard variable not bound to UI is perfectly fine.

This line

```
EmailPool = SomeDataSource.Select(u => u.Email).ToList();
```

doesn't interact with the UI since you're just assigning a value to a non-UI variable (`EmailPool`).

However, when you assign the Source property of your CollectionViewSource, the setter of the Source property signals the UI control to which it is bound that it needs to be updated and **that** is an UI interaction (although indirect through binding).

If you have had a binding directly to EmailPool in your UI, the exception would have been thrown on the line assigning EmailPool.

**EDIT:**  It appears that the CollectionViewSource won't care whether you have bound the Source property to a control or not and will throw an Exception either way.  It would be interesting to check the source code of CollectionViewSource, but it looks like it will always checks the thread ownership no matter what.

**EDIT 2** After looking at the code [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionViewSource.cs/1305600/CollectionViewSource.cs), I was wrong in my first edit.  Source is only a DependencyProperty (CollectionViewSource inherits from DependencyObject) so it must be the default behaviour of any DependencyProperty to validate the thread from which it was created vs the thread from which the value is set.  Bottom line, always edit a DependencyProperty value on the same thread it was created.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to mention this is the post, but I had removed the bindings to either object in the view.  It still throws the exception when setting the CVS.  I'll update my original post.

Comment: Mutating non-UI variables shared between threads may not throw an exception, but that doesn't mean that it's fine.  You need to be *very* careful when manipulating shared state between threads to ensure that the program will function correctly, which means synchronizing access to that shared state in some way.  The fact that you don't get a nice helpful exception when you perform unsafe operations doesn't mean that it'll work, it just means you aren't being (reliably) told that it won't work.

Comment: I edited my answer with the right explanation (I hope)

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you for researching that and allowing me to stop hanging up on this problem.